# gsutil Updates are available check

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil, google-cloud-sdk

On seemly random occasions running a gsutil command it displays:

```
Updates are available for some Cloud SDK components.  To install them,
please run:
  $ gcloud components update
```

My issue is that I run gsutil commands programmatically on a "server" so I don't see this message as it does not appear in either Standard Out or Err from .Net Process.

I see there is a `gsutil version` command but I don't see a query to do a check if I have the current version.

Is there a gsutil, or other GCP SDK command, I can run that will tell me if my local copy needs to be updated with output via Standard Out?

Here is the output from Version -l

```
H:\OUTREACH\WEBSITE\GCP>gsutil version -l
gsutil version: 4.27
checksum: 522455e2d24593ff3a2d3d237eefde57 (OK)
boto version: 2.47.0
python version: 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:40:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
OS: Windows 7
multiprocessing available: False
using cloud sdk: True
pass cloud sdk credentials to gsutil: True
config path(s): xxxx
gsutil path: xxxx
compiled crcmod: True
installed via package manager: False
editable install: False
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gsutil` tool comes with Cloud SDK. When you run `gsutil` it actually invokes a gcloud wrapper which forwards its credentials to `gsutil`. Among other things it occasionally checks if newer versions of Cloud SDK are available.

If you do not wish this check to be performed, you can disable it by setting corresponding `gcloud` property via

```
gcloud config set component_manager/disable_update_check true
```

To actually check if update is available you can run

```
gcloud components list
```

which will display something like

```
Your current Cloud SDK version is: 163.0.0
The latest available version is: 165.0.0
```

To update run `gcloud components update`.

Comment: FYI `gcloud components list' reports the two lines(current and latest + a few more lines) via StandardError. A list of components and versions is sent to StandardOutput.

Comment: Yes, that is gcloud convention. Any data portion of the output is sent to stdout, while extra messages are sent to stderr. For example you can do `gcloud components list --format=json > components.json`, the extra messages will still be printed.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out if a new copy of gsutil is available by running:

```
gsutil update
```

Also, you can avoid having updates offered when running on your server by setting the software_update_check_period variable, as described in https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/update.

Comment: I don't want to run the update - just check to see if an update is needed. When I run `gsutil update` it reports it is depreciated for the SDK.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't pay close enough attention. For Cloud SDK you should run gcloud components update. It will ask whether you want to update if there are updates available, so that provides a way to determine if an update is available without actually applying the update.